# Automatically selected a option according to the text

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var area = {'Mongkok': 1001,'Wan Chai': 1002, 'Sai Kung' : 1003};
</script>
<select id="area">
<option value='0'>choose an area</option>
<option value='1001'>Mong kok</option>
<option value='1002'>Wan Chai</option>
<option value='1003'>Sai Kung</option>
</select>
<input id='address' type='text' />
```

When I enter text (16 Argyle Street, **Mongkok**) the text box #address;
How to use jquery auto select  **Mongkok option(value:1001)** in #area

According to the address text matching area

thanks a lot..

eg

```
//when #address's value='16 Argyle Street, Mongkok' 

//addres var match Mongkok
//then <option value="1001" selected="selected">Mong kok</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** version:

```
$("#address").keyup(function() {
    var adress = $(this).val();
    for (var v in area) {
        if (adress.indexOf(v) >= 0) {
            $("#area").val(area[v]);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bUCHt/3/)

Note that this probably does not scale very well. It has to loop over every element in `area` and if you have a lot, this might become a problem. Also, you might want to add some kind of timeout, so that the code is only run after the user has not typed some text for a short time. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452895/textarea-lags-after-registering-keydown-events-using-javascript).

Comment: when #address's value='16 Argyle Street, Mongkok' ,addres var match Mongkok then <option value="1001" selected="selected">Mong kok</option>

Comment: unbelievable script,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#address").keyup(function(){
        var val = this.value.replace(/ /g,"");
        $.each($("#area option"), function(){
            var optVal = $(this).text().replace(/ /g,"");   
            if(optVal == val){
                (this).attr("selected","selected");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you want entered address as substring, you can change if condition to if(val.indexOf(optVal) != -1)

Comment: You should add a `return false` so that you don't loop over every element once you selected one.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to search for a matching select option when the address is being entered.

Maybe someone can get my jsfiddle example to work. I'm not exactly sure how to check if one string is within another string.
http://jsfiddle.net/gSBWw/